# How to make back to the top anchor link smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i'm trying to make the back to the top button on click to be smooth scrolling but i'm stuck..
at the moment this code works but its not smooth scrolling to the top of the page.. can anyone help me on this?

```
<a id="BackToTop" href="#" title="Back to the top" class="back-to-top hide">
  <span>⌃</span>
</a>
<style>
  .back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 25px;
    color: #999;
    background-color: #243066;
    z-index: 60000;  
  }
  .back-to-top span{
     height: 47px;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .back-to-top:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 25px #9e9e9e;
  }
</style>
<script>
  (function() {
    function trackScroll() {
      var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
      var coords = 300;

      if (scrolled > coords) {
        goTopBtn.classList.remove('hide');
      }
      if (scrolled < coords) {
        goTopBtn.classList.add('hide');
      }
    }

    function backToTop() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0, -80);
        setTimeout(backToTop, 0);
      }
    }

    var goTopBtn = document.querySelector('.back-to-top');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', trackScroll);
    goTopBtn.addEventListener('click', backToTop);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: If the browser support works for you, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView (`behavior: "smooth"`).

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers (everything but IE) support a `scrollTo` method on the window object which you can pass smooth scrolling behaviour to:

```js
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

There are also variations on this such as `element.scrollIntoView()`

Answer (score 0):

You may use that

```
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document
      .getElementById("id")
      .scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    scroll-behaviour: smooth;
}
```